# Angular UI Bootstrap datepicker width issue

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm using Angular UI Bootstrap datepicker popup on a modal dialog. The width of the outside border is not calculated properly based on the inside contents. In some cases, the outside box is bigger than inside contents. In other cases, the outside is smaller. Also, it seems the width of the  outside of the datepicker  has impact on the width of the popup. For example, "col-sm-4" will make the border smaller, while "col-sm-5" will make the border larger.

Can anyone please point me to the right direction to check where the problem might be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured that out. It was a mistake. I have changed the "dropdown-menu" css class buried somewhere, which affects the datepicker layout.

Answer (score 0):

Look this: http://plnkr.co/edit/JTkIvBwl9agQCYxLaN6X?p=preview

```
Just change to: is-open="opened" to: is-open="$parent.opened"
```

So relevant snippets of HTML will look like:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
    datepicker-popup="dd.mm.yyyy"
    ng-model="dt"
    is-open="$parent.opened"
    ng-required="true"
    close-text="Close" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button style="height:34px;" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">
            <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
        </button> <b><- button not working</b>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem. I can't attach images to my question, otherwise it will be more clear what I'm talking about.